# Why can't I connect to the GitLab SSH server?

Tags: git, ssh, rsa

Why can't I connect to the GitLab SSH server?
Something's wrong with my local settings, but I can't find what.

```
$ ssh -Tv -p 9292 gitlab@svn.faktab.net
OpenSSH_7.1p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2d 9 Jul 2015
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to svn.faktab.net [xxx.xx.xxx.xxx] port 9292.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/bls/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/bls/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/bls/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/bls/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/bls/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/bls/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/bls/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/bls/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.1
debug1: ssh_exchange_identification: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
```

Comment: Have you set up a pair of SSH keys and stored it in your `c:/Users/bls/.ssh` folder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request is a response from your webserver. You are using the wrong port for ssh.

Comment: You mean I'm connecting to the wrong port?
In http it's http://svn.faktab.net:9292/, and the default command returns "Bad port"

Comment: I mean that port 9292 is in use for some HTTP service, not an SSH daemon. It normally uses your system's SSH daemon, which normaly runs on port 22.

Comment: Aha! I thought it WAS set excplicitly, but appears it's not. Thanks!

Comment: You can configure it in `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` but I think that that will only influence the generated links to repositories in gitlab. It uses your system's SSH daemon with user `git` by default. in `git`'s `.ssh` directory gitlab adds your users' keys to authorized_keys.